# How to calculate the angle between two points in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, pygame, angle

I want to calculate the angle between two points. For example, say I was making a game and I wanted a gun to point at the mouse cursor, I get the angle it needs to rotate the rotate the gun to that angle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `math` library's `atan2` function,

```py
p1 = (2,2)
p2 = (-1,5)

# Difference in x coordinates
dx = p2[0] - p1[0]

# Difference in y coordinates
dy = p2[1] - p1[1]

# Angle between p1 and p2 in radians
theta = math.atan2(dy, dx)
```

Answer (score 0):

In [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) you can compute the angle between 2 vector by the use of [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) objects and [`angle_to()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.angle_to):

In the following example, (*x0*, *y0*) is the rotation point. (*x1*, *y1*) and (*x2*, *y2*) are the 2 points, which define the vectors form (*x0*, *y0*):

```py
v1 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1-x0, y1-y0)
v2 = pygame.math.Vector2(x2-x0, y2-y0)
angle = v1.angle_to(v2)
```

[`angle_to()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.angle_to) calculates the angle to a given vector in degrees.